# GKE autopilot on the free tier

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to wrap my head around GKE (autopilot) using my personal account.  If I create a GKE autopilot on the free tier I understand it bills me on  vCPU, memory and disk resource requests.  Is this covered under the free tier under free tier of the compute/app engine ?

Answer (score 0):

There is **no cluster management** fee for one Autopilot or Zonal cluster per billing account. For clusters created in Autopilot mode, pods are billed per second for vCPU, memory and disk resource requests and here are the [pricing details](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/pricing) for GKE in Autopilot mode.([source](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free-usage-limits))

From this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/pricing#cluster_management_fee_and_free_tier) :

The GKE free tier provides $74.40 in monthly credits per billing account that are applied to zonal and Autopilot clusters. If you only use a single Zonal or Autopilot cluster, this credit will at least cover the complete cost of that cluster each month. Unused free tier credits are not rolled over, and cannot be applied to any other SKUs (for example, they cannot be applied to compute charges, or the cluster fee for Regional clusters).

Comment: thanks for this, so does this mean if I create an autopilot cluster and use it roughly 2-3 hours a day for a month, it is covered under the free tier ?

Comment: So if I would roughly calculate, for a **single pod in a cluster** using vcpu, memory, storage for 3 hrs a day for 30 days it charges around  $4.450932. So now it depends on how many pods are there in a cluster and note that there is no charge for one Autopilot or Zonal cluster per billing account if another cluster is added then cluster management fee is applied on that cluster.

Comment: Hi @tmp dev, please consider accepting this answer, if it actually answered your question.